# Is it possible to 'symlink' one table to multiple databases [read only] in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have been reading about symlinking and tables etc but have not come across quite what I was after. Can anyone advise whether this is possible:

MySQL server with several databases, all controlled by the same admin. In `database 1`, `table1` contains the master copy of info.
Databases 2, 3, 4 etc are for different companies with their own structures, but each require a table exactly like `table1` with the exact same data, which is fairly static [SELECT only]. Rather than copying `table1` into each database, is it possible to have some sort of symlink or pointer, so that databases 2, 3, 4 would appear to have their own `table1`?

This would be useful eg if there were periodic changes to content of table1, could just update it once. Any advice appreciated.

Comment: just use the dbxxx.tablename directly anywhere assuming sufficient grants given. why symlink and complicate. the tablename should not be used like a cheap file system file

Comment: I think @Drew is correct. But for your further understanding [Try This](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/windows-symbolic-links.html)

Comment: Create a view and adjust the rights accordingly: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-view.html

Comment: sometimes the simplest solutions are by far the easiest. These suggestions seem like the best way to proceed; thanks.